# iframe error when runat="server"

Tags: asp.net

I have a iframe in one of my web pages with `runat="server"` and a javascript function assigned to the onload event.
 When the page renders it gives an error as 
`"CS1012: Too many characters in character literal"`
When I remove the runat="server" attribute it works perfectly but I need the iframe to runat="server".
 How can I fix this?

```
<iframe id='contentFrame' name='contentFrame' 
   runat="server" width="500"
   onload="resizeFrame(document.getElementById('contentFrame'))">
 </iframe>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you use *runat="server"* - 'onload' starts being parsed as C# Event of Html Server Control, like Button.Click. You should set a name of **C# event handler method** in the class of your control/page (NOT JAVASCRIPT). This code will work:

```
<script runat="server">
    void contentFrame_onLoadServer(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            contentFrame.Attributes.Add("onLoad", "contentFrame_onLoadClient();");
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function contentFrame_onLoadClient() {
        resizeFrame(document.getElementById('<%=contentFrame.ClientID %>'));
    }
    function resizeFrame(element) {
        alert(element); // do your logic here
    }
</script>
<iframe 
    runat="server" 
    id='contentFrame' 
    name='contentFrame' 
    width="500" 
    onload="contentFrame_onLoadServer"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "just" add the onload for client side code, because it's "occupied" by the .NET server side onload. You need to hook it up by code (and I enhanced @Philipp 's code):

```
<script runat="server">
void onIframeLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        contentFrame.Attributes.Add("onload", "resizeFrame(document.getElementById('contentFrame'));");
    }
}
</script>
<iframe id='contentFrame' 
    name='contentFrame' 
    runat="server" width="500" 
    onload="onIframeLoad"/>
```

Comment: good catch, I won't update my code, so you get the credits ;)

Answer (score 0):

replace single quotation with double:

```
< iframe id="contentFrame" name="contentFrame" runat="server" width="500" onload="resizeFrame(document.getElementById('contentFrame'))">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not write `document.getElementById('contentFrame')` in onload method. Write it in your javascript function instead.

Answer (score 0):

runat="server" changes the ID of the IFrame.

instead of passing **"document.getElementById('contentFrame')"** pass **"this"** in javascript.

Or you may also pass

```
document.getElementById('<%= contentFrame.ClientID%>')
```